# Solr search across multiple Fields inside of collection and claculationg score

Tags: solr

I need  to implement search across multiple fields in solr collection. I saw a solutions, where new field collector is getting introduced, that includes content of all fields from a whole collection, but what to do if I need to calculate score based on in which field was a hit. For example field "name" is twice more important for me then field "e-mail". Is it possible in Solr?

Comment: Use the edismax handler? `q=foo&qf=name^2 email` will search both `name` and `email` and score hits in `name` with twice the weight as hits in `email`.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for, thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [edismax (and the older dismax) query handler](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/edismax-query-parser.html) supports giving hits in different fields different weights. You can provide a list of fields to search with the parameter `qf` and give their relative weights through the `field^<weight>` syntax:

```
q=foo&qf=name^2 email
```

.. will query for `foo` in `name` and `email`, with `name` being weighted twice as high.

You can combine this with a catch-all field (a copyField instruction that copies the content of all fields into a common field to query), where you weigh hits in the specific fields higher than hits in the catch-all field (named `_text_` here as that's the default one included):

```
q=foo&qf=name^4 email^2 _text_
```